# Set object property explicitly in constructor or implicitly in method?

Tags: php

I have the class A with the `$processorObject` class property that holds an object.

```
class A {
   public $processorObject;
}
```

The object is created in the `initProcessorObject` method. This method is called from constructor of the class A. My question is whether `initProcessorObject` method should return created `processorObject` or should the method assign it to the `$processorObject` property of class A. So:
1) Here the method returns the object:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->processorObject = $this->initProcessorObject();
}

public function initProcessorObject() {
    require_once('/some/path/objects.php');
    return new processorObject();
}
```

2) Here the method assigns the object:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->initProcessorObject();
}

public function initProcessorObject() {
    require_once('/some/path/objects.php');
    $this->processorObject = new processorObject();
}
```

Which one should I choose and why?

//Edited: fixed variable name

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same. Doesnt matter which one you use.

In both cases there will be exactly the same result:

in $this->processorObject will be stored object of processorObject.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm interested in which one is more obvious and will be easier to change if needed

Comment: It doesnt really matter, its on your choice, and also it doesnt matter, if you will need to change it in the future, you will change only one line in code :-)

Comment: Thanks :). Which one would you choose?

Comment: :) second :) I usually dont return objects from function in the same class.